# Conditional Formatting using vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have Sheet 1 as

```
AssocNum      RatePlanCde    RateType     RateTypeDesc
     272       911               2         Adjustable
     472       1115              2         Fixed
```

Many of these **RatePlanCde** are not valid anymore. These have been highlighted in red in Sheet 1. For example, *911* is not a valid **RatePlanCde**, while **RatePlanCde** *1115* is still valid.

I have sheet 2 as

```
AssocNumEID     RateCostComponentCde    RatePlanCde         ReadOnlyInd
272               2                      911                         Null
472               4                      1                           Null
```

I need to find the rows in Sheet 2 where the RatePlanCde is invalid and highlight those rows. Any help in doing this using conditional formatting with `VLOOKUP` will be appreciated.

### UPDATE:

Updating to add more details.
I tried the `COUNTIFS` solution proposed here but for some reason it is not working for me. What am I missing?
I have added a helper column to **Column B** of Sheet1 (aka **RatePlan**) that includes either *Valid* or *Invalid* for the corresponding **RatePlanCde** column (**Column C**).

I am using this formula under conditional formatting in Sheet 2 for conditional formatting:

`=COUNTIFS(RatePlan!$B$2:$B$2514,"Invalid",RatePlan!$C$2:$C$2514,$C2)>0`

[image: Conditional Formatting]

[image: Conditional Formatting 2]

Comment: What does an invalid RatePlanCde look like?  Blank?  Or with the word "invalid"  or simply missing from the list?

Comment: Invalid RatePlanCde is random. It's not in any range. I know its invalid as the customers are not using it anymore and they have highlighted those in Sheet 1. There are 2500 of them that are invalid now. I need to find if they are in any other sheets and highlight those rows in other Sheets too.

Comment: So is the highlighting the only indication that they are invalid?  Or is there some other way to tell?

Comment: In my sheet, the only way to tell they are invalid is that they have been highlighted. I can copy these in a column and add "invalid" string to these. If I do that can it be used in conditional formatting?

Comment: If you have a column that says 'invalid', yes, we can use that.  There is no way to do anything based on the highlighting itself, however.

Comment: So, if I add a column in Sheet 2 on the left hand side of the RatePlanCde with a string "invalid RatePlanCde" and values updated valued e.g "invalid911" then how to use this in condotional formatting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155627/discussion-between-user3033933-and-drewster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize your answer was looking for a solution using **VLOOKUP**, but I think a cleaner method would be to use a **COUNTIFS** formula.

As mentioned by @drewster, you'll first need to add a helper column to **Sheet1**. I placed mine in `Sheet1!Column A` so that it's out of the way of the user and less likely to be corrupted in any way, especially after hiding it, but you can place yours in any convenient column.

There is no formula in `Sheet1!Column A`, only hardcoded values (which you'll need to enter).

*Helper column added to Sheet1*
[image: Visual depiction of a helper column being added to Column A of a worksheet]

Then on **Sheet2** you need to add a conditional formatting rule using the *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* rule. In the formula box under where it says, *Edit the Rule Description*, your formula will be:

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,"Invalid",Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100,$C2)>0`

The ranges I used in the formula - `Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100` & `Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100` - should cover your entire "table" of information on **Sheet1**, so adjust those as needed. `$C2` is the first cell on the conditionally formatted sheet that you are attempting to match to `Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100`.

Also, make sure your rule *Applies to* your entire "table" of information on **Sheet2** (my example uses range `=$A$2:$D$101`, so feel free to change that as well).

*Conditional Formatting Rules Manager for Sheet2*
[image: Conditional Formatting Rules Manager showing Applies to range of =$A$2:$D$101]

*Conditional formatting applied to Sheet2*
[image: Visual depiction of conditional formatting result]

After all of this, you should get your desired result.

Comment: How to populate the helper column with valid/ invalid based on cell color?

Comment: You'll need to do this manually if you're not going to be using VBA. However, you can always apply a filter to your "table" and then sort RatePlanCde by the color red. That should group all of your reds together, making it easier to manually enter the value and then copy and paste to the other rows with red. You can then reapply your filter to sort it by whichever column you want.

Comment: What columns are Column B and Column C in your RatePlan sheet? In your modified calculation, I'd assume Column B is the helper column and Column C is RatePlanCde. Also, the COUNTIFS formula I provided will need to be under conditional formatting in order to get the highlighting for your rows.

Comment: I am trying that. I must be missing something as it did not highlight the rows. I have updated the question with more details with what I did so far. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Was any of this data originally pulled from a database somewhere? It's possible that if it wasn't ALL hand-entered that there may be a conversion issue somewhere (which can be fairly easily rectified). Try this: go to your RatePlan worksheet and in a completely empty cell type `=ISNUMBER(cell)`, with *cell* being linked to the cell that holds your RatePlanCde of 911. What result do you get?

Comment: This results in true. I believe this data was pulled from a database.

Comment: Do both instances of 911 on each worksheet (in the example) return TRUE for this test formula?

Comment: Yes, all instances returned true. I checked with a BA in my team and she said all these tabs were done manually by looking up configuration tables in SQLL and pasting the results into the spreadsheet.

Comment: This does have macros enabled for auto indexing written in VBA. Don't know if that should matter?

Comment: Have you confirmed that no other characters (i.e. spaces) exist in the cells with these numbers?

Comment: No other Characters seem to be present in RatePlanCde in both sheets. Its all numbers.

Comment: And both of your sheets have the column titled *RatePlanCde* in **Column C**?

Comment: No..in sheet 2 the RatePlanCde is not in column C. Should that matter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155637/discussion-between-totsiemae-and-user3033933).